# Html table check if the table element or DOM is loaded completely in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
success: function (listAllDevicesResponse) {    
    if (listAllDevicesResponse.totalCount != 0) {
        $.each(listAllDevicesResponse.devices.device, function (i, device) {
            //if (device.registeredAt != null) {
            var statusload = "loadingStatus_" + i + "";

            var Uidstring = device.uuid.toString();
            var htmlCnt = "<a id='" + device.uuid + "' href='#' id='imgshowfirst' style='width:10px;height:10px;margin-left:15px;'  vpplabel=\'" + vpplabel + "\' onclick=\"return RemoveDevice(this,'" + vpplabel + "');\"> X </a>";
            //Add row

            $("#DeviceTable").append(
                '<tr id=' + device.uuid + '>' +
                '<td>' + device.userDisplayName + '</td>' +
                '<td><div id=' + statusload + ' style="margin-left:10px;"><img src="../../Images/ajax-loader.gif"/></div></td>' +
                '<td>' + htmlCnt + '</td>' +
                '</tr>');
        });
    }
    else {
    }
    }
}

$("#DeviceTable").find('tr').each(function (k) {
    var $tds = $(this).find('td'),
    DeviceId = $(this).attr("id");
});
```

here in ajax success after the DeviceTable table is loaded i want to get the id of each row in the table after ajax success but i m unable to get the row id.please help.thanks..

Comment: i think you code for getting `id` is working before `success` function.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some of the code is cut off, but here's what I think you're posting:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/api/devices',
  data: {},
  success: function(listAllDevicesResponse){
    // code to create a table...
    $("#DeviceTable").append(/* TABLE CONTENTS AS STRING */);
  }
});

$("#DeviceTable").find('tr').each(function (k) {
    var $tds = $(this).find('td'),
    DeviceId = $(this).attr("id");
});
```

The problem with this code is **when** you are iterating the `#DeviceTable`.From this code, you make the AJAX request and then immediately check the table, without waiting for the response.

Make sure the response comes back before iterating the table. If you do it on a button press then just keep the button disabled, then change it like so:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/api/devices',
  data: {},
  success: function(listAllDevicesResponse){
    // code to create a table...
    $("#DeviceTable").append(/* TABLE CONTENTS AS STRING */);

    $('#GoButton').removeAttr('disabled'); // #GoButton should already have the disabled attribute.
  }
});


$('#GoButton').click(function(){
  $("#DeviceTable").find('tr').each(function (k) {
    var $tds = $(this).find('td'),
    DeviceId = $(this).attr("id");

    // Do stuff with the DeviceId...
  });
});
```

**EDIT:**

If you want it to run immediately, then just do it within the `success` callback but after building your table, like so:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/api/devices',
  data: {},
  success: function(listAllDevicesResponse){
    // code to create a table...
    $("#DeviceTable").html(/* TABLE CONTENTS AS STRING */);

    $("#DeviceTable").find('tr').each(function (k) {
      var $tds = $(this).find('td'),
      var DeviceId = $(this).attr("id");

      // Do stuff with the DeviceId...
    });
  }
});
```

But it doesn't really make sense to search the table for those values, since you manually built the table immediately before that. This would work, but make sure you are not iterating through the same list twice.

Comment: JimmyBoh..  thanks for the solution..But actually i dont have any button so after the success i want to get the row id..so how can i check that my table is fully loaded after success..

Comment: I've updated the answer. Although I don't get why you don't just use the current `device.uuid` within your main loop. Don't build the table and then iterate the table just to get each of the `id`'s when you already had that in the first place.